# Convert NULL to default value

Tags: sqlite

I have an old database which I want to give a little update.

The old database had no column contraints like DEFAULT or NOT NULL which was handled (poorly) in the code. For the new database I added these constraints where needed so I can drop the client side code and let sqlite handle it.

Now, the problem is the transition where the NULL values are happily transferred or an error is thrown in case of a NOT NULL constraint.

So **my question is**: how do I transfer the values from one table to another and change all NULL values to the new column's default value?

Currently, this is my (Python) code:

```
    self.cursor.execute("CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_%s AS SELECT * FROM %s" % (table, table))
    self.cursor.execute("DROP TABLE %s" % table)
    self.cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s (%s)" % (table, get_columns(table)))
    self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO %s SELECT * FROM tmp_%s" % (table, table))
    self.cursor.execute("DROP TABLE tmp_%s" % table)
```

The database has many tables, so it's a helper function which creates the sql from the given tablenames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options.  You can either run an update:

```
update table set null_column = default_value where null_column is null
```

Or in your select you can list the columns out and use coalesce.

```
select not_null_column, coalesce(null_column, default_value) from table
```

before you insert to get only not null values.